# How to fix mixed JSON encoded strings

Tags: python, ruby, json, string

I face the following problems. I have JSON strings, where inner arrays/objects are sometimes written as an escaped string and sometimes not. For instance I have

```
{ "author": "Jack",
  "meta": ["a", "b"]}
```

and a bad one:

```
{ "author": "Jack",
  "meta": "[\"a\", \"b\"]"}
```

If I parse the latter one, I will only get a string for the meta property. This can be fixed by passing the meta property again through a JSON parser. The problem, however, if I pass it through `JSON.parse` (Ruby) or `JSON.load` (Python) then maybe I am not dealing with an escaped string, but maybe a simple number `"15.3"`. Which results in an error.

So how I can intelligently detect, whether the value is a value which needs to go through JSON.parse again? Simply try-catch this situation?

Comment: `json.loads('15.3')` works fine in Python.

Comment: I would rather ask the question of how to get consistent JSON formats from whatever cod is outputting the strings rather then trying to figure out how to detect and correct mal-formed JSON.

Comment: Somewhere in the code that outputs the latter JSON is the equivalent of `array.to_json.to_json` (probably due to recursion or embedding of structures)

Comment: @nneonneo Thanks, I missed out on that one.

Comment: @MikeBrant Indeed, that's my oppinion as well. But as I operate on a living patient, I have to fix it somewhere first and then fix it at the source.

Comment: Is the content reliable enough that a hack as simple as just double-decoding if an element has backslashes in it would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the kind of double-encoded data you're dealing with, but testing the first character might be sufficient. If it's `[` or `{` then you could try and decode it with JSON, and if successful, substitute it for that.